# selecting react native push notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I am using react native and trying to add push notification.
My application need push notification because of chatting. I just need push notification to appear whenever the user receives chat message. 
I've searched couple of libraries about push notification and found out `firebase` and `react-native-push-notification`.
Which one is proper library for this case and please tell me if there is other better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using [invertase firebase notification library](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) which is working so far better without any issues.

You'll get almost all the options which you needed for push notification customization like badges, etc.